What is h supposed to represent in the following in the following method for proving limits?
My textbook presents the following general method for proving limits using the delta-epsilon definition:

To prove that:
$\lim{x\to a}f(x) = L$

Set $x = a + h$ and find the distance:

$|f(x) -L| = |f(a + h) - L|$
between $f(x)$ and $L$ expressed with $h$

By calculating the distance from (1), try to find a $\delta>0$ such that if $|h| < \delta$, then the distance is less than $\epsilon$


Its ok to blindly follow this method but I don't get what the variable $h$ is supposed to represent? Another way to frame the question is that I don't get why introducing this variable $h$ and solving with this method works as a proof.

Well, $h$ is $x-a$.
